# react: update state in child component at real-time

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to open dialog (another component) if the user clicks on a button in the first component.

my components are written as a function

**First component:**

```
function Bookings(props) {
      const [dialog, setDialog] = useState(false);

      function openUserDialog() {
           console.log("called")
           setDialog(true)
      }


      return (
          <div>
              <button onClick={openUserDialog}>open dialog</button>

              <BookingsUserDialog isOpen={dialog }/>
          </div>
      );
}
export default (Bookings);
```

**Secont Component (dialog):**

```
function BookingsUserDialog(props) {
const [isDialogOpened, setDialogOpened] = useState(false);

let open = props.isOpen;

if (open){
    console.log("should open dialog")
    // handleDialogOpen();
}

function handleDialogOpen() {
    setDialogOpened(true);
}

function handleDialogClose() {
    setDialogOpened(false);
}

return (
    <div>
        <Dialog
            fullWidth={true}
            maxWidth={"xs"}
            open={isDialogOpened}
            onClose={handleDialogClose}
            TransitionComponent={Transition}
            aria-labelledby="booking-dialog">

            some text

        </Dialog>
    </div>
);
}
export default (BookingsUserDialog);
```

if I called **handleDialogOpen** in **BookingsUserDialog** ,I get

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an
>   infinite loop.

so is the right way to update the state in the child component?
what I want to do is open a dialog when the user clicks on a list item.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off letting your parent component handle whether the dialog is open or closed, the child component doesn't need its own state, it can just use the `isOpen` prop. You can pass the `setDialog` function down to it as a prop as well and then call that with `false` in the dialog's `handleDialogClose` function.

Comment: Remove all state from the child component and pass  both `dialog` and `setDialog` through to it as props from the parent. Use those props anywhere that you would have previously used state in the child.